# How to use the strncpy function in the 3rd array of 2d array strings

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char d2arr[6][7] = {
        { 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' },
        { 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b' },
        { 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c' },
        { 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd' },
        { 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e' },
    };
    char d3arr[6][7][7];
    memset(d3arr, NULL, sizeof(d3arr));

    strncpy(d2arr[0], d3arr[0][0], sizeof(7));
    strncpy(d2arr[1], d3arr[0][1], sizeof(7));
    strncpy(d2arr[2], d3arr[0][2], sizeof(7));
    strncpy(d2arr[3], d3arr[0][3], sizeof(7));
    strncpy(d2arr[4], d3arr[0][4], sizeof(7));

    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][0]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][1]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][2]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][3]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][4]);

    return 0;
}
```

There is no error message, and the results do not come out, so I ask questions.
Please let me know why the string in the 2D array is not copied.

Comment: Use `memcpy`; there are no strings here. And don't use `sizeof(7)`; that is the size of an `int`, and what you need is the size of the target.

Comment: Apart from using memcpy instead of strncpy and not using sizeof(7), have a look at the documentation for strncpy and see which argument that does what.

Comment: @PeteBecker There are indeed strings here. `d2arr[0]` points at the string "aaaaaa"

Comment: To folks who are voting this question down, it's not quite fair. It's a properly asked question (although a very very basic one) ... and I don't think it's a *typo* problem as indicated by others. This should not be voted down.

Comment: @AhmedMasud The main problem is that OP has flipped the arguments for strncpy, and this is something that's easy to check before posting.

Comment: Thank you to everyone. I'll do my best.

Comment: @klutt -- you're right; I got lost in the noise.

Comment: You **know** that the target array is large enough, so there's no need to check how much you're writing. And if you did have to limit the length of what you copied, `strncpy` alone is not sufficient. As written, if the incoming string was too long, correctly calling `strncpy` would just replace one source of undefined behavior with a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not behave as expected:

- the first argument to `strncpy` is the destination pointer.
- the second argument is the source pointer
- the third argument is the size in bytes at the destination to stop the copy **or** up to which to pad with null bytes if the source string is shorter. You pass `sizeof(7)` which is most likely `4` on your system, whereas you should just pass `7`.

Note however that `strncpy` is a very poorly understood function that does not behave as most programmers expect and is error prone for everyone. Here is sound advice about this function: [Stop using `strncpy` already!](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/)

In your case, calling `strcpy` or even `memcpy` works fine.

Also do not use `NULL` for a null byte as the second argument to `memcpy`: use `'\0'` or `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char d2arr[][7] = {
        { 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' },
        { 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b' },
        { 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c' },
        { 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd' },
        { 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e' },
    };
    char d3arr[6][7][7];

    memset(d3arr, '\0', sizeof(d3arr));

    strcpy(d3arr[0][0], d2arr[0]);
    strcpy(d3arr[0][1], d2arr[1]);
    strcpy(d3arr[0][2], d2arr[2]);
    strcpy(d3arr[0][3], d2arr[3]);
    strcpy(d3arr[0][4], d2arr[4]);

    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][0]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][1]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][2]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][3]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[0][4]);

    memcpy(d3arr[1][0], d2arr[0], 7);
    memcpy(d3arr[1][1], d2arr[1], 7);
    memcpy(d3arr[1][2], d2arr[2], 7);
    memcpy(d3arr[1][3], d2arr[3], 7);
    memcpy(d3arr[1][4], d2arr[4], 7);

    printf("%s\n", d3arr[1][0]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[1][1]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[1][2]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[1][3]);
    printf("%s\n", d3arr[1][4]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```
strncpy(d2arr[0] , d3arr[0][0] , sizeof(7) );
strncpy(d2arr[1] , d3arr[0][1] , sizeof(7) );
strncpy(d2arr[2] , d3arr[0][2] , sizeof(7) );
strncpy(d2arr[3] , d3arr[0][3] , sizeof(7) );
strncpy(d2arr[4] , d3arr[0][4] , sizeof(7) );
```

The strncpy function works as under:

```
strncpy(destination, source, no_of_characters);
```

But in your code you have swapped destination and source arrays, and as a result, your code doesn't work. Also instead of using 'sizeof(7)' you should use only '7'. Also you should use strncpy_s instead of strncpy as strncpy can be unsafe.

So after all the corrections, here's the code:

```
strncpy_s(d3arr[0][0], d2arr[0], 7);
strncpy_s(d3arr[0][1], d2arr[1], 7);
strncpy_s(d3arr[0][2], d2arr[2], 7);
strncpy_s(d3arr[0][3], d2arr[3], 7);
strncpy_s(d3arr[0][4], d2arr[4], 7);
```

Just replace the part with strncpy functions with the above code, and you'll be good to go. Other part of the code is totally fine.

Comment: `strncpy_s` takes an extra rsize argument after the destination pointer. It is not a good alternative for the OP.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @SolvedGames What chqrlie is saying is that you, just like OP, have not read the documentation for the functions you're using. :)

Comment: `strncpy` is not a *safe* replacement for `strcpy`, this function made it to the C library by mistake and should not be used. Even if you understand what it does, readers of you code most likely wont.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy`,  [Even folks at Microsoft advise against using it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=36773). `strncpy_s` is an attempt at solving some of the shortcomings of `strncpy`, but this function was shoehorned into the C Standard by Microsoft with disputable ulterior motives.  And [their version behaves differently from the standard one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strncpy-s-strncpy-s-l-wcsncpy-s-wcsncpy-s-l-mbsncpy-s-mbsncpy-s-l?view=msvc-170). Many C libraries do not support it and you use it incorrectly in your answer.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense. I used the function strcpy and got an error that told me to use strcpy_s. That's why I included that in the answer. Thanks for explaining. And as for reading the documentation, I never used the above functions previously and that's why I really never read the documentation.

Comment: You can prevent this warning by inserting `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` or `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)` at the start of your source file.

Comment: @SolvedGames So you used a function you have never heard of in an answer without reading what it does first? That's not good.